# CakePHP Execute query on model and attach it in select

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

In the model i am executing a custom query and pass it to View as following:

```
$countries = $connection->execute('Select id,country from c_countries')->fetchAll('assoc');
$this->set('countries',$countries);
```

And in .ctp file i have the following:

```
<?= $this->Form->input('Country of residence',array('type'=>'select','options'=>$countries)); ?>
```

I want as value the Id and the Text as country. Instead the result seems very strange. Any help please ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Populate country dropdown](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37858904/populate-country-dropdown)

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `find('list')` ORM method as detailed on http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#finding-key-value-pairs