# Populate country dropdown

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have a database table with columns ID , Country.

Inside controller i am getting the countries from model:

```
    $countries = $countries->find('list',array('fields',array('id','country')));
    $this->set('countries',$countries);
```

In the ctp file i am trying to get the a the dropdown by setting in option value the id and in the text the country name.

```
   <?= $this->Form->input('Country of residence',array('type'=>'select','options'=>$countries)); ?>
```

The dropdown is populated by have value the id and as text the id again. How can i get the 'country' as text instead of id ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For [**'list'**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#finding-key-value-pairs), you cannot provide *fields* array as it is just for key/value pairs. You are supposed to specify **keyField** and **valueField** instead.

```
$countries = $countries->find('list', ['keyField' => 'id', 'valueField' => 'country']);
```

Alternatively, you can set the **displayField()** option in your CountriesTable file to have a default *valueField* set for you. Default *keyField* would be the primary key of your table. These options would be set automatically if you [bake](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/bake/usage.html) model for the countries table. And then, you are good to go with just

```
$countries = $countries->find('list');
```

And, **do not use space** in the field name of your form. Go through this [doc](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#creating-form-inputs) once

Answer (score 0):

In your controller change this

```
$countries = $this->Country->find('list', array('fields' => array('id','country')));
    $this->set('countries', $countries);
```

to

```
$countries = $countries->find('list',array('fields',array('id','country')));
$this->set('countries',$countries);
```

here i am change $country to Country(Which is Model name for Country )

And change your view ctp file

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('country_of_residence',array("options"=>$countries,'type'=>'select'));?>
```

to

```
 <?= $this->Form->input('Country of residence',array('type'=>'select','options'=>$countries)); ?>
```

here i am change field Country of residence to field country_of_residence .

its work perfect for you....

thanks